# HTML form input into a table

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, rest

i am new to html, css an javascript and have been looking for an answer to my problem. I wasn't able to find one so i would be really thankful if someone could help me. I am trying to create a REST API with CRUD ressources. It has to have dynamic javascript elements with fetch API connection and a JSON Schema.

I've decided to start with the HTML- Part and got the first html form done. However, it doesn't do anything so i am trying to take the user input an put it at a html table. The table has to be on it's own html-page. 
My HTML form looks like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
            <h1 class="navbar-brand">Ticket System</h1>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <form id="test" action="#" method="POST">
        <div class="container" style="margin-top: 1em">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="Verfasser">Verfasser</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="Titel" required>Titel</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="radio" value="hoch" checked>hoch
                    <br>
                    <input type="radio" value="mittel">mittel
                    <br>   
                    <input type="radio" value="niedrig">niedrig        
            
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="Beschreibung" style="margin-top: 1em">Beschreibung</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" style="margin-bottom: 1em" required></textarea>
                    <button type="submit"class="btn btn-primary">Erstellen</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <pre id="output"></pre>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

i would be really happy if someone could help me.

Comment: "help me" is a pretty vague question. What problem are you having?

Comment: my problem is that it doesn't work. Since i am new to this, the only idea i had was form input into json, json into the table. Sadly, that is not working

Comment: Any errors using F12 tools?

Comment: What doesn't work? You don't have any JavaScript code that does anything with the input.

Comment: that's why i wrote the thread. Because i have never ever in my life done anything with javascript and i was hoping to get some tips or examples how to do it.

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do. Your goals of REST API, CRUD, and JSON are implementation details, but what are you actually trying to build? I would recommend taking a step back and trying to build something simpler if you've never written javascript before. If it's really your goal to build a REST API, that's going to be another large task.

Answer (score 0):

An HTML table is defined with the  tag.

Each table row is defined with the  tag. A table header is defined with the  tag. By default, table headings are bold and centered. A table data/cell is defined with the  tag.

Answer (score 0):

Create your form your form using html and css first. Before you link to submission table.